# Does Rust support using an infix operator as a function?

Tags: rust

I am writing a function that does piecewise multiplication of two arrays.

```
    xs.iter()
        .zip(ys).map(|(x, y)| x * y)
        .sum()
```

In some other languages, I can pass `(*)` as a function to `map`. Does Rust have this feature?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nnn*yes*.  Sorta kinda not really.

You can't write an operator as a name.  But most operators are backed by traits, and you *can* write the name of those, so `a * b` is effectively `Mul::mul(a, b)`, and you can pass `Mul::mul` as a function pointer.

But that doesn't help in this case because `Iterator::map` is expecting a `FnMut((A, B)) -> C`, and the binary operators all implement `FnMut(A, B) -> C`.

Now, you *could* write an adapter for this, but you'd need one for every combination of arity and mutability.  *And* you'd have to eat a heap allocation and indirection *or* require a nightly compiler.

Or, you could write your own version of `Iterator::map` on an extension trait that accepts higher arity functions for iterators of tuples... again, one for each arity...

Honestly, it's simpler to just use a closure.

Answer (score 10):

Rust does not have any syntax to pass infix operators, mostly because it is redundant anyway.

In Rust, each operator maps to a trait: `*` maps to the `std::ops::Mul` trait, for example.

Therefore, using `*` directly should be using `std::ops::Mul::mul`:

```
xs.iter().zip(ys).map(Mul::mul).sum();
```

However there are several difficulties:

1. Generally, iterators yield references while `Mul` is implemented for plain values,
2. `Mul::mul` expects two arguments, `xs.zip(ys)` yields a single element (a tuple of two elements).

So, you need to go from reference to value and then "unpack" the tuple and... it ends up being shorter to use a closure.

Answer (score 3):

No. The `*` operator is implemented in `std::Ops::Mul`, but it can't be used directly:

```
use std::ops::Mul::mul;

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v2 = vec![1, 2, 3];

    println!("{:?}", v1.iter().zip(v2).map(|(x, y)| mul).collect());
}
```

Will result in the following error:

```
error[E0253]: `mul` is not directly importable
 --> <anon>:1:5
  |
1 | use std::ops::Mul::mul;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot be imported directly
```

You could introduce your own function using the `*` operator, but there wouldn't be much added value :).